# Sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, element, javascript-objects

Here's an example of the array that I want to sort looks like.

```
    [ { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393109.png',
        variant: { name: 'original' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/2315456487896.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'original' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393109.png',
        variant: { name: 'r256x200', size: '256x200' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393091.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'r256x200', size: '256x200' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/2315456487896.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'r512x400', size: '512x400' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393091.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'r512x400', size: '512x400' } } ]
```

I want to sort the array based on the nums(string) key. The way I want to sort the array is very simple: let the same numbers group next to each other, i.e.

```
    [ { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393109.png',
        variant: { name: 'original' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393109.png',
        variant: { name: 'r256x200', size: '256x200' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/2315456487896.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'original' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/2315456487896.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'r512x400', size: '512x400' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393091.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'r256x200', size: '256x200' } },
      { nums: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/1375304393091.jpg',
        variant: { name: 'r512x400', size: '512x400' } } ]
```

It doesn't have to be in any order, as long as same numbers group up. What is the fastest way of doing this?

Sorry about the confusion. I guess this is slightly more complicated version of the original question. Anyone has good ideas?

Comment: Have you read the 'Related' links in the right column on this Stack Overflow page? I suspect one of them will help.

Comment: .sort(function(a,b){return a.nums-b.nums});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for comparing numbers:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) { return a.nums - b.nums })
```

for comparing strings (your case):

```
 array.sort(function(a,b) { return a.nums.localeCompare(b.nums) })
```

Comment: glad you made that edit.

Comment: The function used for sorting has to return a number, in case the return one is a negative value, a is before b. If positive b before a and if it's 0 they're equals as long as that function or order is concerned

Comment: How does this work for strings though? Thanks for the response!

Comment: @jensiepoo It works because javascript automatically casts;
you could also use parseInt(string) to make sure

Comment: Question updated. I tried the described way, but seems not to work... Thanks for the input!

Comment: see, you DO need to use <.. for strings.

 take that, @thg435

Comment: But now you are always returning `true` or `false`, (`1` or `0`), never `-1`. Since the OP only wants to group the objects, it might not make a difference, but it's not a correct sort callback.

Comment: @jensiepoo answer updated, works again

Comment: @phiresky: no, `>` is still wrong. Please read the manual (link in the comments to the question).

Comment: @FelixKling okay, updated again just for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the array of objects into an array of strings, and you need to sort the strings:

```
array.map(function(o) {return o.nums;}).sort()
```

That's the closest you can get to the sample output you provided:

```
["1375304393091", "1375304393091", "1375304393109", "1375304393109", "2315456487896", "2315456487896"]
```

Comment: That sorts the property values, but not the objects. (OP seemed to have edited the question)